# Add migration error package manager vs 2017

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem with add-migration I am using entity framework and trying to add a migration to my project which is on windows 10 and its a discord.net bot I am using migrations for a database.

Here is my code for my SQL Database on configuring override

```
namespace bot.Core.DataBase
{
    public class SqlDb : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Creds> Credits { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder Options)
        {
            string DbLoc = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.Replace(@"bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0", @"Core\Data\DataBase.sqlite");
            Options.UseSqlite("Data Source=" + DbLoc);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my database key

```
namespace bot.Core.DataBase
{
    public class Creds
    {
        [Key]
        public ulong Userid { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```